# How-to modify an XSL without having the XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

We have CAD software that outputs data to a `.pdf`, but before that can happen you have to specify an 'xml stylesheet' to be used in the formatting of that pdf.

I don't have access to the software yet, so all I have is the default `.xsl` file they have been using and a sample pdf that has been created with it. The pdf has things they want removed, such as images, which is where I come in.

From my understanding, an .xsl can't standalone, but rather needs to be linked from within the .xml itself, but I don't have the .xml file, so I have to operate under the assumption that this is internalized within the software and it applies the stylesheet on the fly before outputting the pdf. But maybe my understanding is wrong and maybe an .xsl can be used instead of the .xml?

Given this information, what is the best way of isolating the elements they don't want and removing it via the .xsl? I do see the mention of 'images' in various places in the code, but I'm really just blindly removing sections without any regard for what's really going on. I know there has got to be a more sophisticated way of doing this.

For the record, I've never used an .xsl before, which is not helping, but I do have experience with .xml, but nothing overly complicated...simple things for like webpages and such. Any help is greatly appreciated though because this is all new to me.

And for those interested, here is the code (15,000 lines): http://tny.cz/3c8394f0

Comment: Which particular CAD software? If there are any likely looking namespace declarations in that default stylesheet a good start would be to search for those URIs on the web and see if it turns up a schema or other specification for the XML format.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're asking about running an XSL transformation without the `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` declaration in an XML file. You might want to look up some XSLT libraries that have command line executables (Saxon, for example). You can also look at the Microsoft Command Line Transformation Utility (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) if you're on Windows.

Comment: @IanRoberts The software is Tebis, and there are a few namespace declarations being used (see my edit). That's one of the first things I tried looking at, but I don't think I was utilizing this information correctly.

Comment: @austin I don't have an .xml file, just an .xsl file. The software asks for .xsl so it can be used in creating the look of the pdf. Given the pdf I can see the things they don't want, but I'm trying to reverse from there. I will look into your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? You don't show us the XSLT, so we can't tell how difficult it may be to modify it by trial-and-error. IMHO, you should ask the application manufacturer for documentation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I didn't include the .xsl because it's 15,000 lines long. I tried looking for the manufacturer documentation, but came up short. I will look again and try to contact them directly. And the kind of answer I was looking for was something like "this is how you quickly locate all elements that contain relevant images", but I guess without code it's impossible to say. For those that are interested, the code is here: http://tny.cz/3c8394f0

Comment: You can try using the *identity transform* ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)) to get hold of the XML the software is creating internally. It passes through any input unchanged. Your XSLT is [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) which is used for transforming XML into PDF. Analyzing/debugging 15k lines of code is a tough nut, though. However, once you have the original XML and have an idea where the images are in there, you can probably cherry-pick the XSL for the template that processes them.

Comment: @Tomalak I wonder if that will work, given that the result is passed on to the XSL-FO processor to produce the PDF.

Comment: @slime Even if given the XML, modifying a 15,000 lines stylesheet written by someone else is an ambitious undertaking.

Comment: Wouldn't finding and modifying/disabling the template responsible for putting the image in (and then put the 15k-lines monster back) work? Granted, this stands or falls with being able to deduce that from the original XML. But you're right, the XSL-FO processor probably doesn't accept normal XML.

Comment: @Tomalak My point is that applying the identity transform is not likely to produce the original XML, because there is no output at that stage. You are much more likely to end up with an empty PDF, or nothing at all.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I don't know if a stylesheet would be difficult to write that produces XSL-FO in such a way that the resulting PDF would contain the original input (as a text block). OTOH, I have glossed over the 15k lines and graphics are mentioned quite often, but with any luck the OP can simply spot the offending one manually.

Comment: I was able to use a computer that had the software, and it doesn't give you much in the way of settings that you can change that will affect the output, but I did read within the help manual that it's possible to create custom stylesheets, so I think I'm going to try that route...building from scratch instead of trying to reverse this file, but we'll see. Thank you though everyone for the insight. I'll update this thread where necessary.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You should be able to add an `<xsl:result-document method='xml' href='copy-of-input.xml'><xsl:copy-of select='/'/></xsl:result-document>` at the beginning of `<xsl:template match='/'>`. If you have XSLT 2.0, that is.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig And what are the odds of that (XSLT 2.0)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Pretty good, for the tools I use or create. :-) (We're not talking about browsers here.)

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig The stylesheet OP linked declares version 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The .xsl file contains what is known as an “xslt stylesheet,” which is a program that converts XML into something (often XML, HTML, or text). It is itself an XML file.

Sometimes, tools ship XML that contains a reference to some external stylesheet, but that is certainly not required and often not useful, since you may want to use the same xml source as input to different xslt stylesheets.

Honestly, if you have never seen xslt before, you may find it challenging to make changes to the resulting pdf. It is certainly not impossible to do, especially if you have some experience in declarative programming, but xslt is really different from “standard” programming languages. Exposure to Java or Python may not help much here.

I would start by looking for static text snippets inside the information that should be removed. But only to find the likely place to change later, because honestly, I would not start making changes without being able to test them. In any language.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the mechanics of modifying the stylesheet. There are basically two ways you can do it: you can put your modified stylesheet in the place where the CAD software is looking, or you can tell it to look somewhere else. The fact that, in your words "you have to specify an 'xml stylesheet' to be used" suggests that getting the CAD software to execute a modified stylesheet shouldn't be too difficult.

Secondly, assuming you can get it to run a modified stylesheet, how do you make the changes? You will need to understand its input and output. If the documentation is poor then you may need to do some reverse engineering. As a first diagnostic step, you could try modifying the stylesheet to display its input. Even before that step, you might try modifying it with xsl:message instructions to see whether the xsl:message output goes somewhere useful.

And a precursor to all of this is that you need to learn some XSLT. We've all at some stage in our lives attempted to modify programs written in a language we don't understand, and it's a nightmare. The first thing that happens is you get an error message that talks about which rules you have broken, and you have no idea what it's talking about because it's phrased in terms of concepts you've never come across.